# Basic database design and complexity

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am designing a system which has a database for storing users and information related to the users. More specifically each user in the table has very little information. Something like *Name, Password, uid*.

Then each user has zero or more containers, and the way I've initially done this is to create a second table in the database which holds containers and have a field referencing the user owning it. So something like *containerName, content, owner*.

So a query on data from a container would look something like:

```
SELECT content
  FROM containers
 WHERE (containerName='someContainer' AND owner='someOwner');
```

My question is if this is a good way, I am thinking scalability say that we have thousands of users with say... 5 containers each (however each user could have a different number of containers, but 5 would probably be a typical case). My concern is that searching through the database will become slow when there is 5 entries out of 5*1000 entries I could ever want in one query. (We may typically only want a specific container's content from our query and we are looking into the database with basically a overhead of 4995 entries, am I right? And what happen if I subscribed a million users, it would become a huge table which just intuitively feel like a bad idea.

A second take on it which I had would be to have tables per user, however that doesn't feel like a very good solution either since that would give me 1000 tables in the database which (also by intuition) seem like a bad way to do it.

Any help in understanding how to design this would be greatly appreciated, I hope it's all clear and easy to follow.

Comment: Will you have all containers being unique? Or will it be some 20-30 containers shared across all users?

Comment: Hmm.. Every user-container pair is unique but different users may have an instance of "the same container". So in effect the content of userA-containerA differ from the content of userB-containerA, make sense?

Comment: Then you should create a separate table for containers, use `container_id` in the `contents` table and join 3 tables. This will perform much faster and will occupy less space.

Comment: I did a bit of struggling to understand that but I think I see the way you intend for it to work. And it makes sense. So basically the content-lookup would reduce duplication of containers, is that right?

Comment: Correct, right now your design [is not in 2NF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/724032/1154462).

Comment: Thanks, that link was very informative as well. Helped me put the pieces together I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted way of handling this is by creating an `INDEX` on the `owner` field. That way, MySQL optimized queries for `owner = 'some value'` conditions.

See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

You're right in saying that a 1000 tables is not scalable. Once you start reaching a few million records you might want to consider doing sharding (split up records into several locations based on user attributes) ... but by that time you'd already be quite successful I think ;-)

Comment: Wow, thanks that seem to be exactly what I am looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is an RBMS(like Oracle / MySQL) datbase, you can create indexes on columns that are frequently queried to optimize the table traversal and query. Indexes are automatically created for PRIMARY and (optionally for) FOREIGN keys.