# Logical meaning of all the conditions given in all normal forms(1NF, 2NF, 3NF, BCNF)?

Tags: database, normalization

I read all the theoretical blogs that tells about what is normalizationa and all normal forms(1NF, 2NF, 3NF, BCNF). There are some links that I read, [LINK 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), [LINK 2](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php), [LINK 3](http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/3/).

After reading all the three pages, I understand what is normalization, and the basic definition of different Normal forms, with their examples.

But, I am not able to get exact feel, why all these happens, what is the logic behind that.

For example, 2NF says, there should be all non-prime attributes **fully functionaly dependent** on candidte key.

My question is, how above condition helps to remove redundancy ? What is the logical meaning of above condition?

Please give me a answer, that satisfies my query i.e.,  (**Why** this condition helps to remove redundancy ? and **How** it happens ? )

**And advantages of 1, 2, 3NFs**

Comment: Have you already had a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/can-someone-please-give-an-example-of-1nf-2nf-and-3nf-in-plain-english?rq=1)?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I read that answer now. Nicely explained, but my question is how these condition help to remove redundancy ?