# Is this table schema normalized to 1NF and where can I improve?

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization

I've been trying to normalize these tables to 1NF and think I may have done it but was looking for someone to confirm that it's 1NF, all the datatypes look correct and the crows foot look correct?
Here it is: http://i67.tinypic.com/xdy07s.png
The tables represent a behaviour report card system for a school which rates the student on various bahaviour attributes and rates them out of 10.
Please and thankyou! Napstur

Comment: "1NF" is used to mean a lot of different things. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43321127/3404097). Please give a reference to the definition you are supposed to use. Also, please do not use a link or image when you can use text; only text can be searched for or cut & pasted.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, this scheme satisfies 1st NF

A little longer explanation:

1st NF demands that every row in tables are unique.

Look at the scheme you posted: do you see "PK" signs?

"PK" means Primary Key, so this scheme automatically satisfies 1st NF.

And now you can start think about more correct question: "Is this 3rd NF or BCNF or even 4th NF?"

Comment: 3NF is my next goal for sure. I'm almost convinced this is 2NF already as I've seperated EMAIL and PHONE from the other tables, is this correct? If so that's left for 3NF? Thanks! :D

Comment: I made this as an attempt at 3NF, I feel I have way too many FK's not sure if this is right but yeah: http://i67.tinypic.com/2jdj4w6.png

Comment: @Napstur: I have problem with your image, can you repost it some another service? But from bits I remember: your scheme don't have update anomalies except for cases when a person change his/her name and surname.

Comment: Here you go! :) http://imgur.com/a/Hovqa I'm pretty sure this is what you were talking about, let me know if it isn't. Thanks. Rob.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like first normal form to me.  I see no columns holding multiple values and no repeating columns.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Troy. Do the PKs FKs and crows feet look okay too?