# Normalization. Looking for feedback on what should be 3NF

Tags: database, entity-relationship, database-normalization, 3nf, bcnf

I am creating a database for a super market in my database class. The database needs to be at least 3nf but if possible, BCNF. Could someone let me know if this is satisfactory? I believe it is and I just want to make sure.

[image]

Comment: Don't put things into the SYSTEM or SYS schema.

Comment: Relevant: `orderitems` should also have its own price field.

Comment: Please always use text for anything you can. Eg the entire content of this diagram.

Comment: Normalization to BCNF uses functional dependencies, yet you don't mention them. That suggests that you are lacking some fundamental notions about normalization. Why do you "believe it is"?

Answer (score -1):

The values all look atomic, the only problem I see is in your *System.orders* table. 3NF should not store calculated values.

[Here's a good topic page on calculated values.](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/01/database-skills-third-normal-form-and.html)

The other one I'm not sure about is the lack of a primary key on *System.orderItems*. I've been told it's good practice for each table to have a Primary Key. On your relational table, you make both orderId and itemId a linked Primary Key.

[Here's a good discussion on the need for a Primary Key.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840162/should-each-and-every-table-have-a-primary-key)

Hope that helps.

Comment: **Total** in the _System.Orders_ table - Total is quantity * price.

When I learned Normalization the values had to be atomic. A calculated value isn't atomic, it's dependent on the value from two other tables.

Comment: "Calculated", "computed" and "generated" are used re a column evaluated by the DBMS. Such a column can be ignored in normalization, *because* it is calculated. The question doesn't say it's calculated in that sense. Regardless, the NFs a table is in are a function of its possible values, but TOTAL would be a function also of some other table(s), and that constraint/redundancy would not affect NFs. (Although it is relevant to good design.) (Also in Orders it would be a sum of products.) In OrderItems (as a product) it's the same situation. Price & quantity both in Orderitem would violate 3NF.

Comment: You are also misusing the term "atomic", which does not have to do with functional dependencies. (And although "[atomicity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24038895/3404097)" has to do with some definitions of "normalized" & "1NF", those definitions are more or less irrelevant to higher NFs, which don't care what the types of columns are.)

Comment: Atomic, the value is not divisible or capable of further decomposition. A total value is by definition composed of values from two other tables, is divisible and decomposable. It's not atomic, nor is it 3NF.                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029620/what-is-atomicity-in-dbms

Comment: I just gave a link to my answer to that linked question. (And the answer by MikeSherrill'CatRecall' is also very good.) Your comment is not clear, I don't know what you are trying to say, but it doesn't look like anything that I haven't already contradicted. You need to learn about FDs & normalization to higher NFs from a textbook, presentation or course. (Many are online.) Good luck.

Comment: I did learn normalization from a textbook. I quoted atomic from the textbook. No calculated values should make it to the third normal form. If you turned this in as a project for any normalization class, it would be rejected because of the calculated value.

Comment: PS [Normalization in database management system](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097)