# can foreign key be recurred in one row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, relational-database

in forwarders project 
I have a table named Ports

```
portid
portname
```

has a relationship 1 to many to quotation,

```
Quotationid
Qoutationdate
POL
POD
```

- port of loading , port of discharge.

I want to show the user dropdownlist shows the portname in POL and POD and save portid in both fields

So,can foreign key be recurred in one row?  , thanks in advance.
And how to make it in MVC model

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/24243417/3404097.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Foriegn keys are nothing more than just ordinary columns/attribute, except they only contain references to other relations. There's nothing wrong in having recurring foreign keys in a tuple/row.

Comment: Thank you very much, would you mind to tell me how to make it in MVC model

Comment: Which MVC specifically as there are lots of MVC patterns with lots of implementation differences between languages.

Comment: You can simply define multiple properties in your model class like [ForeignKey("portid")] public Ports POL { get; set; }
 [ForeignKey("portid")] public Ports POD { get; set; }