# First normal form violation

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, database-normalization, first-normal-form

Let's say a user can have multiple phone numbers.

I can understand that the first table below is a violation of 1NF, as the `userID=2` is repeated.

```
+--------+-------+
| userID | phone |
+--------+-------+
| 1      | 1010  |
| 2      | 1020  |
| 2      | 1021  |
| 3      | 1030  |
+--------+-------+
```

But is this second table also a violation of 1NF ? Yes, it appears to be a bad, inflexible design - but is it violating 1NF ?

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| userID | phone1 | phone2 |
+--------+--------+--------+
| 1      | 1010   |        |
| 2      | 1020   | 1021   |
| 3      | 1030   |        |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: First example is not a violation, since userId is atomic

Comment: `userID=2` getting repeated seems to be a violation - at least according to this wikipedia example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Examples

Comment: @KayaToast: You've misread the Wikipedia article. But [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202535/562459) gives a much better explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalization in database management system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623169/normalization-in-database-management-system)

Answer (score 1):

It is a violation of 1NF.
1NF requires that

1. There are no multiple-valued fields in the table.
2. There are no repeating groups in the table.

`phone1`, `phone2` etc are repeating groups, violation of 1NF.

repetition of userID=2 does not violate 1NF itself.

Answer (score 0):

What happens to your second design when you have a third telephone number? It may not be a violation of 1NF but it's poor design. I, for example, have a home telephone number, a work telephone number, a mobile telephone number and a fax number. The ERP program which I use at work has a 'user contacts' table which has fields for each of those numbers. This allows for easier output but can sometimes lead to problems if a person has more than one number of a given type.

The standard way of handling multiple telephone numbers is to have a separate table with fields owner, telephone number and description.

Comment: Thanks for your effort in responding. But it is a very specific question - does it violate 1NF ? I have already stated/acknowledged in my question that it is a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first table isn't violating the 1st NF because there are no multi-valued attributes. It's respecting the normal form. The second table follows the same logic as the 1st.

You can check it in the image explanation of the tutorial in the link that shows a violation and a refactor of the violation to the normal form. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/first-normal-form-1nf/) [image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)