# When creating a table, is it possible to declare multiple columns to have the same type without repeatedly mentioning the type?

Tags: mysql

When creating a table in mysql, if I declare multiple columns to have the same type, is it possible to declare it without repeatedly mentioning the type?

For example:

```
create table courseMarks ( mark1 integer, mark2 integer, mark3 integer, mark4 integer, mark5 integer, mark6 integer);
```

I googled "mysql create table several columns same type" but can't find a solution, or I miss something.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a long series of columns of same data type and similar names like your example, it's likely a case of [Repeating Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194292/normalization-what-does-repeating-groups-mean) — violating 1st normal form.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible the data type is not a facultative argument as you can see it in the [Mysql Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

The facultative arguments are in [... ]