# Select array from array mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have two table
Table Category (Cate_id, Parent_id)

```
Cate_id | Parent_ID

1       | 0

3       | 1

2       | 0

4       | 1
```

And table Products (Product_id, Category_id)

```
Product_id | Category_id

1          | 1,3

2          | 4
```

How to select product ID with category_id = 1 and category have parent = 1?

Comment: The problem you are encountering (or going to encounter) is that Category_id within the Products table is denormalized.  [Normalize it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Don't. Ever. Store. Delimited values in the relational database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are 1NF, 2NF and 3NF in database design?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/what-are-1nf-2nf-and-3nf-in-database-design)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to design table schema then you should use `normalization` to optimize.

There are **no arrays in MySQL** and also *there is no need for it*.

First off all, if a "column in a RDBMS is meant to be atomic", in that it contains one and only one piece of information. Trying to store more than one piece of data in a column is a "violation of first normal form".

So you should have to alter your logic like below,

```
-------------------
|Cate_id |Parent_ID|
--------------------
|1       | 0       |
--------------------
|3       | 1       |
--------------------
|2       | 0       |
--------------------
|4       | 1       |
--------------------

--------------------------
|Product_id | Category_id|
--------------------------
|1          | 1          |
--------------------------
|1          | 3          |
--------------------------
|2          | 4          |
--------------------------
```

Hope this query will solve your problem then.

```
Select prdct.Product_id
from Products as prdct, Category as ctgory
where 
  ctgory.Cate_id = prdct.Category_id
  and prdct.category_id =1
  and ctgory.Parent_ID=1;
```

Comment: But the category_id is array, it will be (1,3,4)

Comment: There is no arrays in MySQL since there is no need.