# Best way to store a friend's list of every user

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to store a friend's list of every user in SQL server database.
I am confused

1. should I use table for every user, or
2. should I just use one table for everyone, or
3. Is there any other best way (I'm going to query it frequently)?

And how can I get all the friends of the single user when I query?

Comment: It's not a good practice to have a dedicated table for every user. Normally it will be a table for everyone (your option 2), and a relation table to specify the relationship between users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we say SQL Server then we are saying RDBMS.

Then there is [normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/what-are-1nf-2nf-and-3nf-in-database-design) INF, 2NFand 3rdNF..., this is your question how to normalize a user and his friends data base.

My View, you need three tables

```
Individual (IndId (PK), Name ...)
User (UserId (PK), IndId (FK to Individual Table), login, password etc)
Friends(FID(PK), UserId (FK to User Table), IndId (FK to Individual Table))
```

**Get all friends of a user**

```
Select I.* from Friends F
     JOIN User U on F.UserId=U.UserId // Get all friends of all users
     JOIN Individual I on I.IndId =F.IndId // Get there names etc
   Where I.Name = 'MyFriend' // filter a friend
```

Comment: OK,I will create 3 tables then how can I get all the friends (userIds) of a single user

Answer (score 2):

what i did was created first table for list of all **tbl_users** . then created another table for **tbl_friendslist**. the function of **tbl_friendslist** table is to store the id of the users table  ex. user 10 added user 11 the data will be stored in the **tbl_friendslist** table and i user ENUM to flag if the user 11 accepted,declined the request..

Answer (score 1):

You should have 2 tables:

**TBL_Users** will have a `User_ID`

**TBL_Friends** will have a `Friend_ID` and a `Friend_User_ID`

The correlation will be between `TBL_Users.User_ID` and `TBL_Friends.Friend_User_ID`

Answer (score 1):

You need two tables. 
User (id,UserName,...)
UserFriendShip(Id,ToUserId,FromUserId,RequestStatus,RequestStatusReason)

Example: I want to be friend with you (We are users so user table has our records)

ToUserId : Your user Id
FromUserId : My User Id
ResquestStatus: Requested, Accepted, or else enum value so use tinyint not int for enum values in sql server.
RequestStatusReason: This area is very important. Think that you first accepted and then rejected me. this area will store that detail.

Specify your necessities and then you can design it yourself I just tried to examine.