# c# and SQLite, query execution is slow

Tags: c#, sqlite

I start by saying that I'm a beginner with C# and SQL, so sorry if my code contains some rubbish.

I've a sqlite table which is a Japanese Dictionary.
It has the following rows:

**ID**: an unique, autoincremental integer;
**word**: the word in Japanese "ideograms" (es.: 元気);
**reading**: the phonetic reading of the word (es.: げんき);
**definition**: the dictionary definition for the word;

A word may appear more than once inside the dictionary.
Sometimes there may be multiple entries where both "word" and "reding" are the same, and I need to retrieve all of them:

**ID - word - reading - definition**
1 - 愛 - あい - Love;
2 - 愛 - あい - The title of a 1800 book by ... ;

This is how I retrieve the result:

```
void Search(string _word, string _reading) //es.: Search(愛, あい);
{
    ...
    using(var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=dictsdb.sqlite;Version=3;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE word = '" + _word + "' AND reading = '" + _reading + "'";

        using(var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    (...)
                }
            }
        }
    conn.Close();
    }
...
}
```

The dictionary is not sorted in a particular way, so I can not use optimized search algorithms.
I can not sort the dictionary either because I need it in its actual order.

The slow part is the `command.ExecuteReader()`.
I suppose because for each search it must check all the entries of the dictionary, which is huge.

Any suggestion to make it faster?

EDIT: Thank you all for your suggestions! The index trick solved the issue and now is teen times faster! Thank to the other suggestions too, like the parametrized input one!

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not inject raw strings into your queries. **Always** [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp) any and all user data or you'll create awful [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: SQLite is not MySQL. Please correct your title and tags unless there is some aspect of MySQL that actually relates to your question.

Comment: @tadman beat me to it :)

Comment: Show the SQL table definition, does it use indexes?

Comment: Away from the answer, you don't need to open and close the connection  since you're using "Using" statement.

Comment: _"I can not sort the dictionary either because I need it in its actual order."_ There is no implicit order in SQL database tables; if you need an "actual order" you must store such ordering information with the data to be ordered; you should not rely on rows to be (or remain in) the order they were added.

Comment: @AbdullahDibas the [constructor does not create an open connection](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection~_ctor(String).html), so the call `conn.Open()` is still required.

Comment: @dlatikay thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Aside from ensuring you have the proper indices, don't create a new connection for every query. Open your database once and query it repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speed up the query, add an index to the `dictionary` table, include at least the `word` column ([reference](https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#fig4)):

```
CREATE INDEX IdxDictionary ON dictionary(word);
```

Depending on the number of readings per word, it may be worth comparing performance to that of a multi-column index:

```
CREATE INDEX IdxDictionary ON dictionary(word, reading);
```

The multi-column index will take up more space than the first one; if storage is of no concern, you can just create the second one.

When we assume that `_word` and `_reading` are both user input, they need to be parametrized to prevent users from hacking your database:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE word=@word AND reading=@reading";

using(var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", _word);        
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reading", _reading);        

    ...
}
```

If the number of expected matches is high, you could further optimize: Fetch only the `ID` and `definition` columns, `word` and `reading` are redundant.

Answer (score 2):

First off, congrats on starting your first C#/SQLite project, best of luck mate. I would recommend looking into restructuring your data a bit. For example:

1) **Table Structure.** It sounds like there is a many to one relation on your word -> reading definitions. Meaning, you have many reading that may use the same work multiple times. You could then restructure your table structure to represent something like this:

```
   JD_Word               JD_Reading
|------------|         |------------|
|     ID     |  |----->|     ID     |
|    Word    |  |      |   Reading  |
| Reading ID |--|      |------------|
| Definition |
|------------|
```

2) **Indexing.** In general, it may be a good idea to create a simple index. As an overview, and index reduced the number of data pages your database has to scan. In SQLite, your primary key should be automatically indexed. More on that [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_indexes.htm). You could create a multi column index on your JD_Reading Table:

Current Structure:

```
CREATE INDEX dictionary_word ON dictionary(word);
```

Current Structure w/Muti-Column

```
CRAETE INDEX dictionary_word ON dictionary(word, reading);
```

[3NF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/what-are-1nf-2nf-and-3nf-in-database-design) (See first point):

```
CREATE INDEX dictionary_word ON JD_Word(Word);
CREATE INDEX dictionary_reading ON JD_Reading(Reading);
```

3) There are many other options! Check out [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB&fromgroups#!topic/csharp-sqlite/f8v7yTLPlMk) highlighting some C#/SQLite performance issues. Leave a comment if you have any questions mate. Happy Programming.