# specific field content shorting by specific separator

Tags: mysql

I need to sort the content of the column `field1`. It is a list of numbers separated by semicolons.

**Input**:

```
id    field1
-------------
1     20;5;10
2     15;20;5
```

**Output**:

```
id    field1
-------------
1     5;10;20
2     5;15;20
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you not save the values in a new table with foreign keys to this table? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/what-are-database-normal-forms-and-can-you-give-examples/724032#724032

Comment: This data have been stored from long time in a single input field. Now client want to short it.

Comment: Is it possible to change the tables to the 3NF? Because this question is exactly the reason why you should normalize the tables.

Comment: This input take from single UI input. So no way..