# Database management system

Tags: database

Why we can say that a table is in 3nf is also in 2nf please explain with example because 3nf required condition to fulfilled is either determinant should be super key or determine set should be prime attribute

Comment: The following should cover what you require. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/what-are-database-normal-forms-and-can-you-give-examples/724032#724032

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are database normal forms and can you give examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/what-are-database-normal-forms-and-can-you-give-examples)

Comment: Why is is required determinant should be super key or determine set should be prime attribute in 3rd nf